# ExoPlayer download and encrypted video suddenly quitting in Samsung Tablet

Tags: android, exoplayer

This error came while playing next downloaded AES encrypt video.
**A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x6d594634 (code=2), thread 22625 (Loader:Extracto)** pls help me anyone knows already I spent more time, but no-one giving proper solution.(In mobile it's working perfectly)

Answer (score 0):

> A **SIGSEGV** is an error(signal) caused by an invalid memory reference or a segmentation fault. You are probably trying to access an array element out of bounds or trying to use too much memory.

It is probably a audio/video decoding problem by the device.
Please open an issue on ExoPlayer github repository : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues

Best